# Zipping a file in memory from a byte string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently I am writing a file like this:

```
with open('derp.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(file_data)
```

However sometimes this file is very large and I need to zip it, I'd like to minimize the number of writes to disk and do this in memory. I understand I can use `BytesIO` and `ZipFile` to create a zip file from the data. This is what I have so far:

```
zipbuf = io.BytesIO(file_data)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(zipbuf, 'w')
z.close()

with open('derp.zip', 'wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(zipbuf, f)
```

How can I make it so that when you extract the zip file there is the original `derp.bin` inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile('derp.bin','w')
z.writestr('derp.zip',file_data,8)
z.close()
```

Comment: at list in my python the name of the files need to be reversed: `z = zipfile.ZipFile('derp.zip','w')` and `z.writestr('derp.bin',file_data,8)` instead of what is written.